# Using Get-AzMetric from PowerShell to get "CpuPercentage" metrics from Azure Classic Cloud service returns error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a fairly simple requirement that is giving me some grief.  I am trying to use the `Get-AzMetric` cmdlet for PowerShell to extract average percent CPU usage metrics for an Azure Classic Cloud service.  (This would be the same information as found in the portal under Monitoring -> Metrics.)

For my simple script I have isolated to the following:

```
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount

Get-AzMetric `
    -ResourceId "/subscriptions/8xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/...xxx" `
    -TimeGrain 00:15:00 `
    -MetricName "CpuPercentage"
```

The `ResourceId` is copied and pasted directly from the Azure portal for the Classic Cloud service that I am trying to get the metrics for.  From all appearances I am following the documentation correctly from [Get-AzMetric (As.Monitor) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-4.5.0#syntax), however I keep getting a `BadRequest` response that is not particularly insightful:

```
Get-AzMetric : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message:
    Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException:
    Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong with my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in short, two errors in this case.

1.If you copy the `Resource ID` directly from the `Properties` in the portal, it is the resource id for the cloud service, its resource type is `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames`, which is not supported by the `Get-AzMetric` command.

Actually, the information under `Metrics` in the portal is for the web role, its resource type is `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots/roles`.

[image]

2.The `MetricName` in your command is wrong, it should be `Percentage CPU`, not `CpuPercentage`.

---

So in conclusion, actually your command is used to get the metric of the web role in the cloud service, please change the parameters like below, it will work.

```
$metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/<cloudservice-name>/slots/production/roles/WebRole1" -TimeGrain 00:15:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU"
$metric.Data
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, those two things you pointed out were indeed the problem!