# Get-AzMetric command is returning error when trying to access App Service Plan metrics

Tags: powershell, metrics, azure-app-service-plans, azure-runbook

This is my code:
i check permission correct and check documentation but i dont found de answer.

```
$metricParams = @{
    ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($resourceGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$($appServicePlanName)/Metrics"
    MetricName = "CPU Percentage"
    Aggregation = "Average"
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)  # Inicio de la consulta, por ejemplo, para la última hora
    EndTime = Get-Date  # Fin de la consulta
}
```

```
Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricsOperationsExtensions.<ListAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Metrics.GetAzureRmMetricCommand.ProcessRecordInternal()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet(), Code: Null, Status code:Null, Reason phrase: Null
```

Error in my job azure runbook whnen i run it..

Comment: You are getting status 404 Not Found.  Either the route is bad or you do not have permission to read the route.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-not-found?tabs=bicep

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-10.3.0), The **`Get-AzMetric`** command uses **`microsoft.web/sites`** resource type and resource id to get the metrics **which is the metrics of Azure Web app** and Azure web app does not contain CPU Percentage metrics. CPU Percentage metrics is included in App Service plan. **For Azure App service plan metrics you need to refer this [Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azappserviceplanmetrics?view=azps-0.10.0)** which uses **`Get-AzAppServicePlanMetrics`** command to get CPU Percentage metrics of App Service Plan:-

First get the resource id with resource type microsoft.web/sites to use it in your command like below:-

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName siliconrg -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites
```

**Output:-**

[image]

*Use this ResourceID in your Get-AzMetrics command like below:-*

```
Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/sub-id/resourceGroups/siliconrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/siliconwebapp096" -TimeGrain 00:01:00
```

**Output:-**

[image]

In order to get App Service Plan CPU percentage, Refer the script from this [**Document2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azappserviceplanmetrics?view=azps-0.10.0#code-try-2):-

```
$currentTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"


$endTime = $currentTime

$startTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)


$startTimeFormatted = $startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")


Write-Host "UTC Start Time: $startTimeFormatted"
Write-Host "UTC End Time: $endTime"

Get-AzAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName "Resource-group-name" -Name "Appservice-plan-name" -StartTime 2023-09-23T07:21:06Z -EndTime 2023-09-23T13:51:06Z -Granularity PT1M -Metrics ["CPU Percentage"] -Debug
```

Reference - [Using Get-AzMetric from PowerShell to get "CpuPercentage" metrics from Azure Classic Cloud service returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402354/using-get-azmetric-from-powershell-to-get-cpupercentage-metrics-from-azure-cla) By Joy Wang